# Getting Infinite Loop Babylonian Algorithm R

Tags: r, algorithm

I am trying to do the Babylonian Algorithm in R and can't quite figure out where I'm wrong. Basically, I'm trying to calculate the square root of `x` using the Babylonian algorithm. It consists of guessing the root of `x`, - (let's call this `r`). Let's say the guess was  `r = x/2`. We replace `r` with the average of `r` and `x/r` until `|r^2 - x| < 10^-6`. I also want to return the root along with the number of iterations it takes.

This is my code, but I'm getting an infinite loop.

```
root = function(x, t = 10^{-6}
    r = x/2
    i = 0
    while(abs(r^2 - x) > t{
        r = (x + x/r)/2
        i = i + 1
    }
    return(list("sqrt.x" = r, "n.iter" = i))
    }
```

Comment: should it be `r = (r + x/r)/2` (after sorting out your brackets)

Comment: Wow. good catch lol. Can't believe I didn't catch that.